# ImageCell with accessories in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'd like to build a TableView with ImageCells with Accessories(right arrows) like in the Settings on the iPhone.
But not sure how to implement it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass the Xamarin.Forms ImageCell, create a CustomRenderer for your subclass and set the Accessory for the iOS UITableViewCell to DisclosureIndicator in the GetCell method of the Renderer.

Edit 7/21 (Adding example code)

**MyImageCell.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public class MyImageCell : ImageCell
    {
        public bool ShowDisclosure { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyImageCellRenderer.cs**

```
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyImageCell), typeof(MyImageCellRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.iOS
{
    public class MyImageCellRenderer : ImageCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var c = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            var view = (MyImageCell)item;
            c.Accessory = view.ShowDisclosure
                ? UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator
                : UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, please. Code examples will be great.